# struct in C: Error storage size of 'params' isn't known

Tags: c, struct

I'm a bit new to C and I'm having a bit of trouble with a project I'm currently working on. Essentially I have the following files: main.c, alarm.c, alarm.h

I have a struct declaration in alarm.c that looks like:

```
#define STRLEN 150;

struct alarmparams
{
    char time[STRLEN];
    char duration[STRLEN];
    char snooze[STRLEN];
    char port[STRLEN];
};
```

In main.c I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "alarm.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    struct alarmparams params;

    printf("%s, %s\n", params.time, params.duration);
}
```

And in alarm.h I have:

```
struct alarmparams;
```

Right now when I go to compile I get the following error:

```
error: storage size of ‘params’ isn’t known
```

I've looked through other posts regarding this error, so I have done a bit of research on this already. I've also tried some of the suggested solutions and it's either I get the exact same error or I got more on top of it. I'm at a lose as to how to fix this.

Is there something I'm missing? Did I declare something incorrectly?

In general should structs be declared in the header file or the c file? Or does it even matter? What's the different between:

```
struct foo {...};
```

and

```
typedef struct foo {...};
```

Comment: Well, just `typedef struct foo {...};` is a syntax error; you need an identifier to serve as the new type name.

Comment: What is the definition of STRLEN?  Possibly the storage size isn't known is because that isn't defined.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mentioned that. I did define STRLEN in my code. (See edit)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
struct alarmparams;
```

is the declaration of an incomplete type. You can create a pointer to an object of this type but you cannot declare an object of this type or take its size until it has been completed. You have to make its complete declaration visible in `main.c` to declare an object of its type.

If you use the type in both `alarm.c` and `main.c`, just declare it in `alarm.h` and include `alarm.h` in `main.c`.

For you second question, the difference between:

```
struct foo {...};
```

and

```
typedef struct foo {...} foo_;
```

is in the latter case you also declare an alias `foo_` for the type name `struct foo`.

Comment: And don't forget to put guards on the header files so he doesn't get multiple declaration errors.

Answer (score 7):

You have to declare the structure in the header file `alarm.h`.

At the moment, when you include `alarm.h`, the code in main doesn't see the structure composition, all it sees is `struct alarmparams;`, so it doesn't know how long it is. How can you allocate space for something that you don't know how much space it takes?

`typedef struct foo { ... };` is invalid: `typedef` expects you to provide an alias for a type. `typedef struct foo { ... } foo_t;` would be correct.

`typedef` is a storage class specifier, thus, you can think of it as any other regular declaration. Imagine you want an alias `foo` for the type `bar`: just declare a variable of type `bar` and call it `foo`. Now, prepend a `typedef` keyword behind, and you are done. Even complicated `typedef`s can be easily understood with this simple approach. Since `struct foo { ... };` would be an invalid declaration for a variable (no name is provided), so is `typedef struct foo { ... };`.

In general, declare structures in the header file when you will reuse them in other source files. If you don't plan on doing so, declaring them on the .c file should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, the value of `STRLEN` must be known at compile time (it most likely is in this case, but just in case).

Comment: Sorry, I do have STRLEN defined in my code. I just forgot to include it above.